# manage fade in animation of listitems with onScrollStateChanged for a listview

Tags: android, animation, scroll, fadein

animate `ListView` items with fade-in animation, with `onScrollStateChanged`,

I have been trying out below code

```
LayoutAnimationController controller = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(
                this, R.anim.anim2);
        getListView().setLayoutAnimation(controller);


        getListView().setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(scrollState == 0) {
                    LayoutAnimationController controller = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(
                            MainActivity.this, R.anim.anim2);
                    getListView().setLayoutAnimation(controller);

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**how it works**

when we load the `ListView`, first the items fade in

when we scroll up or down then fade in effect is applied to all the items (VISIBLE) in the list

**What I want**

suppose we have a list of 20 items

now when the list would load first 10 items are visible , the fade in effect is applied to these 10

when we scroll down the already visible list-items should stay as it is, and fade in effect should be applied to remaining items, which were invisible earlier, example, if we scroll to 15th item the previous 5 items(from the earlier 10)[which are still visible] should stay as they are, and animation should be applied to the remaining 5 (of the total 15)[which will now be visible]

**What happens with above code**

the fade in effect if we scroll down or up applies to all items that are visible , including the previous 5 items and the next 5 items

my questions are

1) can we identify which items have already been visible and animation has been completed for them (and prevent animation being applied to them)

2) apply animation to the remaining item which will now be visible